# Using Fragments/FragmentActivity to retain data across activity re-creation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, retain

I've been looking at the android documentation and diverse sources around the web, but I can't seem to get my app to retain data across activity re-creation (like pressing the back button to exit and then entering the app from the icon or the task manager).

I have 3 classes: the main one (extends FragmentActivity), a fragment and a class that should run in the background while the app is not active, and after the activity is created, it needs to update the fragment.

Here are my sources:

**Main**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentExample mFragment;
    private BackgroundClass bgClass = new BackgroundClass();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        manageFragment(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    protected void manageFragment(FragmentManager fm) {

        mFragment = (FragmentExample) fm.findFragmentByTag("TAG");

        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = new mFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(mFragment,"TAG").commit();
        }

        else fm.beginTransaction().attach(mFragment).commit();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFragment = bgClass.update(mFragment);
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class FragmentExample extends Fragment {

    //declare variables

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        //initialize variables from View

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //more initializations
    }
}
```

**BackgroundClass**

```
public class BackgroundClass extends SomeOtherClass {

    //declare variables

    protected FragmentExample update(final FragmentExample fExample) {
        //update listeners, variables, etc
        return fExample;
    }

//Overridden methods from SomeOtherClass

}
```

Currently it updates the data only when I change the configuration (i.e. rotating the screen). Any sort of help would be great.

Comment: These scenarios -- the BACK button in particular -- are handled in Android no differently than they would be in most other applications for most other operating environments: save the data as you go.

Comment: That would be one way to do it, but I thought there was a way to maintain the BackgroundClass object for the activity, as opposed to saving data periodically on the device.

Comment: Only by saving it to a file, database, etc. As a temporary cache, you can stuff data in static data members, but your process will not live forever. Do not confuse holding onto transient data or cached data with storing it "for realz" somewhere persistent.